# use 'find' to search for directories !containing certain filetype foo

Tags: bash, directory, find

I have a few directories, some with a depth of 3, which contain mixed file types. What I need to do is to `rm -rf` all the subdirectories that do not contain filetype `foo`.

Is this achievable with `find` somehow?
I do know that I can use find like this:

```
find . ! -name '*.foo' -delete
```

to delete all files within the directories that do not contain any file of type `*.foo`. 
Now, how can I use this, to not only delete all unwanted files, but all directories and subdirectories which do not contain `*.foo`?

Comment: So if you have `/a/b`, and `b` has no `*.foo` files, but `/a/b/c` has `*.foo` files, obviously we don't want to run `rm -rf /a/b`, right?  In this case, I don't think `rm -rf` is the right approach, maybe we need something like `rm dir/*; rmdir dir`.

Comment: If a directory contains `some.foo` and `some.bar`, should it be deleted? Your question is not clear in this respect.

Answer (score 5):

*(Your question is not clear: if a directory contains `some.foo` and `some.bar`, should it be deleted? I interpreted it as requiring such a directory to be kept.)*

The following script should work, provided that no file name contains a newline and no directory matches `*.foo`. The principle is to traverse the directory from the leaves up (`-depth`), and as `*.foo` files are encountered, the containing directory and all parents are marked as `protected`. Any reached file that is not `*.foo` and not protected is a directory to be deleted. Because of the `-depth` traversal order, a directory is always reached after the `*.foo` files that might protect it. Warning: minimally tested, remove the `echo` at your own risk.

```
find . -depth -name '*.foo' -o -type d | awk '{
    if ($0 ~ /\.foo$/) {
        while (sub("/+[^/]+$", "")) {protect[$0]=1;}
    } else {
        if (!protect[$0]) {
            gsub("[\\\001-/]", "\\\\&"); # protect file names for xargs
            print;
        }
    }
}' | xargs echo rm -rf
```

<sub>For once, I'm not proposing a zsh solution.</sub>

Comment: Maybe [`File::Find`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Find) would be the right tool for this job.

Comment: I get an error on awk script line 5 running that, but it seems OK if I change `[\\\011-/]` to `[\011-]`.

Comment: @Mikel: That's weird, I get no error under Gawk, Mawk or the original awk, and I don't see what could be wrong. Your regexp `"[\001-]"` (I assume `\011` is a typo) matches only `\001` and `-`, which is no good since the point is to protect `\\'"` and whitespace.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant `\001`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure this can be done using only `find`, but I think we can do it using only `bash` and `find`.

```
tree_contains_foo_files()
{
    # return true (0) as soon as we find a "*.foo" file
    find "$1" -type f -name "*.foo" -print0 |
        read -r -d $'\0' file && return 0

    return 1
}

find . -depth -type d -print0 |
while read -r -d $'\0' dir; do
    if ! tree_contains_foo_files "$dir"; then
        rm -rf "$dir"
    fi
done
```

Given this test tree:

```
.
./dir1
./dir1/dir1.1
./dir1/dir1.1/dir1.1.1
./dir1/dir1.1/dir1.1.1/file.foo
./dir1/dir1.1/file.bar
./dir2
./dir2/dir2.1
./dir2/file.bar
./dir3
```

I get this result:

```
rm -rf ./dir2/dir2.1
rm -rf ./dir2
rm -rf ./dir3
```

which I think is what you want, i.e. don't delete `dir1`, because `dir1/dir1.1/dir1.1.1` contains `file.foo`.

But note that it does process directories multiple times, so it might be slow for large trees.  If efficiency is important, I'd use a more powerful programming language.

Comment: There are more efficient implementations of `tree_contains_foo_files`, such as `[ -n "$(find … | head -c 1)" ]`, or (faster but requires GNU find) `[ -n "$(find … -printf a -quit)" ]`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  You're right I should short-circuit as soon as a file is found.  Seeing as I'm using `read` already, how about `find ... | read file && return 0`.  I think that is very slightly faster again.

Comment: Or of course `find ... | read -n 1 ...`.

Answer (score 1):

IIUYC, you can simply first remove all unwanted files using

```
find . ! -type f -name '*.foo' -delete
```

which may empty some directories. Then you can remove the empty directories (and directories containing only empty directories, etc.) like in [my question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8430/how-to-remove-all-empty-directories-in-a-subtree/8433#8433)

```
find . -depth -mindepth 1 -empty -type d -exec rmdir -p -- {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

If more than just `find` is allowed, a much simpler solution is:

```bsh
find -type d -not -path . | while IFS='' read -r path; do [[ ! -e "$path/$notThisFile" ]] && echo "$path"; done
```

Replace `-e` with any test you like.

This should print you all sub-directories that don’t contain `$notThisFile`.

---

Verbose example, where all non-hidden sub-directories that contain the file are highlighted:

```bsh
find -type d -not -path . | while IFS='' read -r path; do
  [[ ! -e "$path/$notThisFile" ]] && echo "$path"
done | sed -r 's~^([^.]*)/'"$notThisFile"'$~\033[1;37m\1\033[0m~''
```