# How to remove all empty directories in a subtree?

Tags: directory, find, rm

How can I remove all empty directories in a subtree? I used something like

```
find . -type d -exec rmdir {} 2>/dev/null \;
```

but I needs to be run multiple times in order to remove directories containing empty directories only. Moreover, it's quite slow, especially under cygwin.

Comment: See also http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/12190/2264 for an emacs solution.

Answer (score 327, accepted):

Combining GNU `find` options and predicates, this command should do the job:

```
find . -type d -empty -delete
```

- `-type d` restricts to directories
- `-empty` restricts to empty ones
- `-delete` removes each directory

The tree is walked from the leaves without the need to specify `-depth` as it is implied by `-delete`.

Comment: `-delete` already implies `-depth` so you don't need to specify that manually.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that. Answer updated.

Comment: A lot simpler than the accepted answer, and it does the job at least just as well!

Comment: I would add ```-mindepth 1``` here, to prevent from deleting the starting directory itself, if it would be empty.

Comment: Great, but doesn't work on my old SunOS hosts...

Comment: @GregDubicki Thanks for that tip. Just what I was looking for.

Comment: Great, but how would I omit directories with specific names, I've tried `!(Completed)`, but it threw a `-bash: !: event not found`

Comment: `!` has a special meaning for the shell. You need to escape it. Something like: `\! -name 'Completed'` just before `-delete` should work. Or you just put a marker file in this directory.

Answer (score 60):

List the directories deeply-nested-first.

```
find . -depth -type d -exec rmdir {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

(Note that the redirection applies to the `find` command as a whole, not just to `rmdir`. Redirecting only for `rmdir` would cause a significant slowdown as you'd need to invoke an intermediate shell.)

You can avoid running `rmdir` on non-empty directories by passing the `-empty` predicate to find. GNU find tests the directory when it's about to run the command, so directories that have just been emptied will be picked up.

```
find . -depth -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;
```

Another way to speed up would be to group the `rmdir` invocations. Both are likely to be noticeably faster than the original, especially under Cygwin. I don't expect much difference between these two.

```
find . -depth -type d -print0 | xargs -0 rmdir 2>/dev/null
find . -depth -type d -exec rmdir {} + 2>/dev/null
```

Which method is faster depends on how many non-empty directories you have. You can't combine `-empty` with methods for grouping invocations, because then the directories that only contain empty directories aren't empty by the time `find` looks at them.

Another method would be to run multiple passes. Whether this is faster depends on a lot of things, including whether the whole directory hierarchy can remain in the disk cache between `find` runs.

```
while [ -n "$(find . -depth -type d -empty -print -exec rmdir {} +)" ]; do :; done
```

Alternatively, use zsh. The [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) `F` matches non-empty directories, so `/^F` matches empty directories. Directories that only contain empty directories can't be matched so easily.

```
while rmdir **/*(/N^F); do :; done
```

(This terminates when `rmdir` receives an empty command line.)

Comment: That's it. Instead of 90 seconds it takes 0.90 s.

Comment: @maaartinus: I'm curious: do you have a similar data set where you could try without `-p`? I wouldn't have thought it would make a difference.

Comment: @maartinus — other little optimizations: adding `-empty` should work with this one (although I'm not sure exactly how much it'll gain). And very, very trivially, since you probably don't want to remove `.`, use `-mindepth 1`.

Comment: It was not the removal but the process start up overhead, what took nearly all the time. I had overlooked the `-depth` argument, which makes `rmdir -p` useless. I've changed my comment already. The 90 s was my original attempt; there's nothing surprising here.

Comment: @mattdm: `-empty` will not work: if you have `a/b` with `b` empty and the only entry in `a`, `find` would not consider `a` empty. And I expect `-mindepth 1` to be slower (probably not measurably so) because it adds an extra test for each file just to very rarely skip calling `rmdir` on `.`.

Comment: @Gilles: `-empty` works with `rmdir -p`; not otherwise. And although I haven't tested, `-mindepth 1` is an _option_ rather than a _test_, and therefore should only happen once. At least, I think. (That also may be a GNUism.)

Comment: @mattdm: oh, right, `-empty` does work with `rmdir -p`. As to whether it helps, I think not, but it's not clear-cut: `-empty` + `-p` means fewer calls to `rmdir(1)` (for large data sets) but more calls to `rmdir(2)` and `stat(2)`.

Comment: I realized we can remove the `rmdir` command call altogether, at least with GNU find, with this command: `find . -depth -type d -empty -delete`

Answer (score 7):

`find . -depth -type d -exec rmdir {} +`

is the simplest and standard compliant answer to this question.

The other answers given here unfortunately all depend on vendor specific enhancements that do not exist on all systems.

Comment: This answer raises an error for each directory that cannot be deleted which may be less than desirable.

Comment: @WillemvanKetwich, add a `2> /dev/null` to hide those.

Comment: It will also fail if you deal with a huge amount of directories, as there is a limit on how many characters `rmdir` can accept. Using `\;` instead of `+` will fix this issue, but it will make the command significantly slower.

Comment: Also all these solutions will fail with hidden files, like `.DS_Store` on Mac or `Desktop.ini` on Windows.

Answer (score 6):

If you just tack a `-p` on your `rmdir`, that'll work in one pass. It won't be pretty or optimal, but it should get everything. That tells rmdir to remove any non-empty parent directories of the one you're removing.

You can save a little bit by adding the `-empty` test to find, so it doesn't bother with non-empty directories.

Answer (score 1):

I use these aliases for frequently used `find` commands, especially when I cleaning up disk space using *dupeguru*, where removing duplicates can result in a lot of empty directories.

Comments inside `.bashrc` so I won't forget them later when I need to tweak it.

```bsh
# find empty directories
alias find-empty='find . -type d -empty'

# fine empty/zero sized files
alias find-zero='find . -type f -empty'

# delete all empty directories!
alias find-empty-delete='find-empty -delete'

# delete empty directories when `-delete` option is not available.
# output null character (instead of newline) as separator. used together
# with `xargs -0`, will handle filenames with spaces and special chars.
alias find-empty-delete2='find-empty -print0 | xargs -0 rmdir -p'

# alternative version using `-exec` with `+`, similar to xargs.
# {}: path of current file
# +: {} is replaced with as many pathnames as possible for each invocation.
alias find-empty-delete3='find-empty -exec rmdir -p {} +'

# for removing zero sized files, we can't de-dupe them automatically
# since they are technically all the same, so they are typically left
# beind. this removes them if needed.
alias  find-zero-delete='find-zero -delete'
alias find-zero-delete2='find-zero -print0 | xargs -0 rm'
alias find-zero-delete3='find-zero -exec rm {} +'
```

Answer (score 0):

`find . -type d -printf "%d %p\n" |\
    sort -nr |\
    perl -pe 's/^\d+\s//;' |\
    while read dir; do \
        (rmdir "$dir" > /dev/null 2>&1); \
    done`

Here's how it works:

1. Recursively list all the directories along with their depth
2. Sort by descending order of their depth
3. Filter out only the directory paths
4. Run `rmdir` on the list one by one

Answer (score 0):

Found a simple but effective solution which should be also POSIX compliant:

```
while find /path/to -type d -empty -print -exec rmdir {} + | grep -q ^; do :; done
```

It's looping a `find` command which executes `rmdir -v` in every round. If no more empty dirs are found, no output is generated, `grep` returns negative and breaks the loop.

One solution of https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8433/496909 is quite similar. It's utilizing a subshell and this a `grep`. Don't know which one is better.

PS: If you're interested in the removed directories just remove `-q`.

Comment: `-empty` is not POSIX. busybox can be built with `-empty` supported and `-delete` not though

Answer (score -2):

`rm -r */` command worked easily for me. `rm` should require `-f` to forcefully remove directories with files. `rm -r` should only remove empty directories. I'm open to why this could be wrong. This should also leave files since `*/` only looks at folders.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend to test it thoroughly first as `rm` is primarily meant to remove files. While `*/` only matches directories, I have no idea what it does on deeper levels. I can also imagine that it works on some systems only.

Comment: Slippery slope in its finest.