# How does this command work so that the parent directory will be deleted after its subdirectories are deleted?

Tags: find

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24163/167166

> ```
> find . -type d -depth -empty -exec rmdir "{}" \;
> ```
>
> That will first drill down the directory tree until it finds the first
>   empty directory, then delete it.  Thus making the parent directory
>   empty which will then be deleted, etc.  This will produce the desired
>   effect (I do this probably 10 times a week, so I'm pretty sure it's
>   right). :-)

How does it work so that the parent directory will be deleted after its subdirectories are deleted?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

From the [`find` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html):

> `-depth` Process each directory’s contents before the directory itself.  The `-delete` action also implies `-depth`.

With

```
find . -type d -depth -empty -exec rmdir "{}" \;
```

`find` starts in the current directory, and looks for all files and directories contained therein (and in children etc.); it then processes each one, starting with the contents of a directory before processing the parent directory. Imagine the following tree:

```
.
├── a
│   ├── c
│   └── d
│       └── e
└── b
```

`find . -depth` shows the order in which this will be processed:

```
./a/c
./a/d/e
./a/d
./a
./b
.
```

As you can see, the children are listed before the parents. In a more complex `find` command, the actions would be applied to children before parents; in the example you give, empty leaf directories will be processed first, and if they’re empty, deleted; then their parents will be processed, and in turn if *they’re* empty (which might be the case since their empty children have been deleted), deleted too, and so on all the way back to the current directory.

If you omit `-depth`, `find` processes files in enumeration order, for example

```
.
./a
./a/c
./a/d
./a/d/e
./b
```

So `.` is processed first; it’s not empty so it’s left alone. Then `a`, and the same applies. Then `a/c`; that gets deleted since it’s empty. `a/d` is left alone, `a/d/e` is deleted, as is `b`. But `find` doesn’t revisit the directories it’s already processed, so `a` and `a/d` remain even though we want them to be deleted.

Comment: As an additional note: here one can't use `-exec rmdir {} +` instead of `-exec rmdir {} \;` to avoid running one `rmdir` per directory as that would delay the running so `find` would not delete the parent as it would not be empty at the time of the check (it would become empty later when `rmdir` is run when enough arguments have been accumulated). With some `find` implementations including yours, you cause use `-delete` (which implies `-depth` as noted, so `find . -type d -empty -delete` would be enough). That saves a rmdir execution and also removes some race conditions.