# how can I recursively delete empty directories in my home directory?

Tags: linux, filesystems, find, rm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove all empty directories in a subtree?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8430/how-to-remove-all-empty-directories-in-a-subtree)

I create directories very often, scattered over my home directory, and I find it very hard to locate and delete them.

I want any alias/function/script to find/locate and delete all empty directories in my home directory.

Comment: This does not answer your question, but could solve the underlying problem.  I often use the construct:  `WORK=$(mktemp -d)` or `cd $(mktemp -d)`.  Of course don't put important files that you need to preserve in those directories.  But most likely your system is already setup to automagically make those files disappear after a while.

Comment: I have my machine mount a tmpfs ram drive to the `/z/` directory on start-up and do all my temporary work there.

Answer (score 543, accepted):

The `find` command is the primary tool for recursive file system operations.
Use the `-type d` expression to tell `find` you're interested in finding directories only (and not plain files). The GNU version of `find` supports the `-empty` test, so

```
$ find . -type d -empty -print
```

will print all empty directories below your current directory.

Use `find ~ -…` or `find "$HOME" -…` to base the search on your home directory (if it isn't your current directory).

After you've verified that this is selecting the correct directories, use `-delete` to delete all matches:

```
$ find . -type d -empty -delete
```

Comment: Good solution, but it should be noted that not all version of find have `-empty`.

Comment: @Baldrick Doesn't looks from `home` directory if I run it form `~/Desktop`.

Comment: @Santosh: The command as it is, is meant to be run from your home directory (that's why I added `~$` in the beginning). If you want to run it regardless of your working directory, use `"$HOME"` instead of `.` as jordanm suggested in his answer.

Comment: @jordanm: You're quit right, I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Baldrick Just a last task. I want to escape my `~/project` directory.

Comment: @Santosh: You can use something like this: `find "$HOME" -type d \! -path "$HOME/project/*" -empty -delete`. The `!` operator (or the escaped `\!`) returns false if the following expression is true. In effect, it excludes the `~/project` directory. Note that if `~/project` is empty, it will be deleted.

Comment: Consider changing the second example to `.` instead of `~`. If somebody copy-pastes this without noticing and only checks the output of the first this can have bad consequences.

Comment: I would add ```-mindepth 1``` here, to prevent from deleting the starting directory itself, if it would be empty. It's not really probable case for ```$HOME``` but if you would use this on any other directory..

Comment: I had to use `$ find . -type d -empty -delete`

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul Wasn't that already mentioned in answer?

Comment: Maybe you are new to SE, but you can see that the my comment was added on October, and the answer was edited in November to include it! There is no need to spam everyone over a year after it was answered!

Comment: It seems that it doesn't see hidden files. How to do it ?

Comment: BSD version under macOS 10.12 has `-empty`.

Answer (score 25):

You can call `rmdir` on every directory, since `rmdir` will only delete a directory if it is empty:

```
find "$HOME" -type d -exec rmdir {} + 2>/dev/null
```

If you also want to print the directories being removed, you will need to check if they are empty:

```
find "$HOME" -type d -exec bash -c 'shopt -s nullglob; shopt -s dotglob; files=("$1"/*); [[ ${files[@]} ]] || rmdir -v "$1"' -- {} \;
```

Here is a pure bash example (version 4 or higher):

```
shopt -s globstar
for dir in **/; do
   files=("$dir"/*)
   [[ ${files[@]} ]] || rmdir -v "$dir"
done
```

Comment: And what if I only want to find/locate and not delete?

Comment: @Santosh - In either of the last two examples, just change `rmdir -v` to `echo`.

Comment: BusyBox `find` doesn't have `-empty`, so the `-exec` trick is helpful. But rather than sending errors off to /dev/null, it's better to tell rmdir to suppress them, e.g. `find . -type d -depth -exec rmdir -p --ignore-fail-on-non-empty {} \;`

Comment: These commands have terrible performance since they create a new process for every directory found. When using that approach, you really should at least use something like `find ... | xargs -n 100 rmdir` to delete them in batches. Even then, it won't work properly because it will fail to remove early directories that will later become empty because of later empty directories' removal. Thus you'd need to execute it several times.

Comment: @jlh No, the first command will only execute `rmdir` once. That's the difference between using `+` and `\;` for terminating a command in `find`.