# How to find empty directories in unix

Tags: find, directory

I want to show all the empty directories under my home directory, using shell script, can you help me find the code? (without using `find`'s `-empty`)

Answer (score 33):

Using GNU `find`:

```
find ~ -type d -empty
```

(this looks for empty directories starting from your home directory).

Answer (score 4):

If your find has no `-empty` flag (like for exmaple the one from `busbox` or any other [POSIX-conformant `find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html)), you have to do it that way (inspired by @[jordanm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/13796/jordanm)'s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46324/52727)), using `bash`:

```
find . -type d -exec bash -c 'shopt -s nullglob; shopt -s dotglob; 
  a=("$1"/*); [[ ${a[@]} ]] || printf "%s\n" "$1"' sh {} \;
```

- `-type d` find only directories
- `-exec bash -c '...' sh {} \;` calls a bash shell for every found directory

  - `shopt -s nullglob; shopt -s dotglob` in that `bash` instance, `nullglob` prevents bash from returning the pattern when matching nothing. `dotglob` includes files and directories beginning with a dot (`.`).
  - `a=("$1"/*)` fill the array `$a` with all items in processing directory
  - `[[ ${a[@]} ]]` check if `$a` contains items. If not...
  - `printf "%s\n" "$1"` prints the directory name

---

If you want to process that list further, make sure to delimit the items by nullbyte:

```
find . -type d -exec bash -c 'shopt -s nullglob; shopt -s dotglob; 
      a=("$1"/*); [[ ${a[@]} ]] || printf "%s\0" "$1"' sh {} \; | xargs -0 ...
```

Comment: wow great! how did you came up with this?

Comment: This is a bit of a Rube Goldberg machine. Aside from not having any issue with OS’s that use link count of mount points for private purposes (a rather arcane use case), this incantation has no benefit I can see over the linked duplicate answer (which, to be fair, I wrote) using `-links 2` at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/248986/147196 — and, if set loose on a large directory tree, it will be _much_ less performant than the `-links` answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find empty directories that are *in* your home directory, except of all empty directories under home tree, you can use GNU `find`:

`find ~ -maxdepth 1 -type d -empty`

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention that our teatcher want us to do so without using -empty (that's the hard part)

Comment: @EmEsEn, I'm sure your teacher wanted you to think and learn.