# Delete Empty Folders - recursive

Tags: find, pipe

I would like to clean up some folders. So I want to delete all folders which are empty or only contain other folders...

First I tried

```
find . -type d -delete
```

but this lists the subfolders after the parents, so I would have to execute it multiple times.

So I tried using tac and pipes

```
find . -type d | tac | xargs rmdir
```

This one fails on whitespaces, etc, so I need a masking - now I am stuck...

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to remove all empty directories in a subtree?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8430/12779)

Comment: Nope. I want also to remove non-empty folder, which contain only folders!

Comment: The -depth option will do what you want...

Comment: multiple times? how often?... thats why I want to do it recursive

Comment: At least in GNU 'find', the `-delete` action also implies `-depth` i.e. directories containing only other directories *become* empty as the command executes from the bottom of the tree up.

Comment: @steeldriver Why should someone use vendor specific extensions when the task can be done using only standard compliant features?

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type d -depth -exec rmdir {} +
```

should work if you have a halfway recent find(1) - note that execplus was added in 1989 ;-)

Note that there was a hint that there may be non-standard find implementations that emit a warning when `-depth` was not specified as the first `primary`.