# List folders which contain only a subfolder named Attic

Tags: command-line, files, find

I'm cleaning up a CVS repo before migration to git. As part of the preparation I need to find (and possibly remove) any folders which ONLY contain an `Attic` folder.

My unix-fu is not strong, but here's what I attempted, which doesn't work, but hopefully conveys the intent.

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in **/*
do
  if [ -d "$file" ];then
    if [`ls | wc -l` == 1 && `ls Attic | wc -l` == 1]; then
      ((echo Attic-only folder))
    fi
  fi
done
```

The second part to this is to then find any folders (or folder chains, rather) that are empty.

For example, if `/foo/bar/Attic` is removed, and `/foo/bar` are now both empty, lets kill that part of the tree too.

Background: I'm trying to clean up a CVS repository for migration to git. CVS creates an `Attic` folder for deleted files. Over the last 10 years some Bad Things have happened. I am fully aware of the risks and implications. I have backed up my data and I'm working on a copy.

Comment: Wouldn't removing the `Attic` folders break the history of the repository?

Comment: In these cases, no. It's mostly when people have accidentally added a new folder and files under the wrong name, then simply deleted the entire folder and re-added under a different name.

Comment: They wouldn't be part of the checkout in any case (if using `cvs up -P`), so I think you may be doing more harm than good with removing them. Try importing into Git without removing them and see what happens first. This may be a no-problem.

Comment: What about the `CVS` directories?

Comment: @Rahul That simply finds ALL folders containing an attic folder.  I'm only interested in folders if they contain ONLY an Attic folder.

Comment: @SatoKatsura He's doing this on the repository, not the checkout. (I hope)

Comment: @Kusalananda true, they may not be a part of the conversion, but as it currently stands, the conversion is taking 30+ hours. By removing stuff I know I don't want or need in the migrated version, I've already trimmed it down to a 7 hour process. Besides, this question is more about how to do it, rather than the merits of doing so :)

Comment: @Rahul if a folder contains `,v` files and an `Attic` folder, it can stay. If the only contents of a folder is the attic folder, it can go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `bash`, GNU `find`, and `comm`:

```
comm -12 \
    <( find /path/to/CVS/repo -printf '%h\n' \
        sort | uniq -u ) \
    <( find /path/to/CVS/repo -name Attic -type d -printf '%h\n' | \
        sort )
```

The first `find` prints `basename`s (`-printf '%h\n'`) of everything, files and directories, in the repository.  `sort | uniq -u` then prints directories with exactly one descendant, file or directory.

Then the second `find` prints the `basename`s of the `Attic` directories.  The intersection of this set to the set above (i.e. `comm -12`) are exactly the directories with only an `Attic` descendant.

This of course happily ignores things like symlinks and other fun, and filenames with embedded newlines.  You shouldn't have those in a CVS repo anyway.

Comment: Can this be piped into something like `rm -rvf` ?

Comment: @DenhamCoote Sure, you can pipe the output to `xargs -d '\n' rm -rvf`.  Or to `tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 rm -rvf`, if your `xargs` doesn't support `-d`.  Both assume you don't have filenames with embedded newlines.

Comment: while I haven't seen any with newlines, I know there are filenames (and folders) with spaces in them, which breaks if I try to pipe to something like du -ch. Anyway, I shall try your suggestions. Thank you for your helpful answer.

Comment: @DenhamCoote No problem with spaces.  Fatal problems with newlines.

Answer (score 4):

Find all `Attic` folders in `.` without any siblings, in bash:

```
find . -type d -name Attic -print0 | while read -d $'\0' DIR ;\
    do [[ $(ls -1 "$DIR/.." | wc -l) -eq 1 ]] && echo "$DIR" ; done
```

Replace `echo` with your favorite file handling command ;-).

Answer (score 3):

The first part seems to be easiest to do with a bit of Python:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, sys

for topdir in sys.argv:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(topdir):
        if not files and len(dirs) == 1 and dirs[0] == 'Attic':
            print os.path.join(root)
```

Run it like this:

```
./script.py /path/to/CVS/repo
```

To delete the directories, assuming your files don't have newlines embedded in names, and assuming a cooperating `xargs` (i.e. one with the `-d` option):

```
./script.py /path/to/CVS/repo | xargs -d '\n' rm -rf
```

With a non-cooperating `xargs` you could modify the script to print `NUL`-terminated strings:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function
import os, sys

for topdir in sys.argv:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(topdir):
        if not files and len(dirs) == 1 and dirs[0] == 'Attic':
            print(os.path.join(root), end="\0")
```

Then you'd use `xargs -0` to kill the directories:

```
./script.py /path/to/CVS/repo | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

To kill empty directories after that:

```
find /path/to/CVS/repo -depth -type d -empty -delete
```

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`:

```
twoormore () {                                            
set -- $REPLY/*(D[2])
(($#))
}
```

The function evaluates true if there's more than one item in `$REPLY` (`D[2]` selects the second item from whatever that glob expands to). It can then be used via glob qualifiers:

```
print -rl -- **/*(D/e_'[[ -d $REPLY/Attic ]]'_^+twoormore)
```

This searches recursively (`**/*`) for all directories (`/`) - including hidden ones (`D`) - and lists only those for which both the `e`string and the negated (`^`) function evaluate `true` i.e. there's a child directory called `Attic` and it's the only item in `$REPLY`.

---

Similarly, with `find`, you could run:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c '
if [ -d "$0"/Attic ]; then
set -- "$0"/*
if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
printf %s\\n "$0"
fi
fi
' {} \;
```

Comment: To remove empty dirs see [How to remove all empty directories in a subtree?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8430)

Comment: Thanks for the additional link - That's the next stop on my journey today :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `ksh`/`bash`:

```
find /cvs/myrepository_copy -type d -name "Attic" -print |
while read -r attic; do
  things=( $( dirname "$attic" )/* )
  if (( ${#things[@]} == 1 )); then
    echo rm -rf "$( dirname "$attic" )"
  fi
done
```

**Make a copy of the whole repository**, then run this (on the copy, preferably).  Inspect the output with your eyes and brain and remove the `echo` if you think it does the right thing.

You may have to run it several times to remove higher level directories that became empty (only containing an `Attic` directory) upon earlier runs of the loop.

I'm uncertain how this handles exotic filenames, but as `*` in only used to check if there is *anything* other than `Attic` in the folder, that may not be an issue.

I take no responsibility for the loss of data.

Comment: "Inspect the output with your eyes and brain" - that made my day. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this command

```
find $(find . -type d -exec bash -c "echo -ne '{} '; ls '{}' | wc -l" \; |  awk '$NF==1{print $1}') -name Attic -exec rm -r {} \;
```

Comment: This only works if you don't have directory names with spaces.  It's also slow (it spawns 4 processes per directory).

Answer (score 1):

Using a bash function `f` for filtering the list of Attic folders with `find`:

```
f(){ [ $(ls $(dirname $1)|wc -l|xargs echo) == 1 ] && dirname $1; }
export -f f
find . -wholename "*/Attic" -type d -exec bash -c 'f "$0"' {} \;
```

`xargs echo` is used for trimming the string returned by `wc -l` (may not be needed on some systems).

Can also be written as a oneliner by separating the above line with semicolons.