# How to extract a specifically named folder from a recursive directory, delete the others?

Tags: directory, directory-structure, mv, recursive

I have this kind of directory tree that is obtained from unzipping a zip file:

> x -> y -> z -> **run** -> FILES AND DIRECTORIES HERE

So there are 4 directories, 3 of whom are empty of files (x, y, z) and only contain 1 sub-directory, and there is the directory I am interested in, named "**run**".

I want to move the "run" directory itself (including everything within) to the "root" location where I unzipped (i.e. where "x" is, but not inside "x").

Assumptions: There **exists** a folder named "run", but I do not know how many directories I will have to "cd" to get to it (could be 3 (x,y,z), could be 10 or more. The names are also unknown and do not have to be x,y,z etc).

How can I accomplish this? I tried many variations of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8430/how-to-remove-all-empty-directories-in-a-subtree) but they all failed.

Comment: I'm afraid the picture isn't very clear, no. [Please don't post screenshots of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). I can't even read the directory name in your picture. All I see is a dim blue blur.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

what about

```
  find . -type d -name run -exec mv {} /path/to/X \;
```

where

- /path/to/X is your destination directory
- you start from this same place.
- then use other answer to remove empty directories.

(on a side note there is a `--junk-paths` option in zip, either when zipping or unzipping)

Answer (score 7):

I would do this in `bash`, using `globstar`. As explained in `man bash`:

```
globstar
      If set, the pattern ** used in a pathname expansion con‐
      text will match all files and zero or  more  directories
      and  subdirectories.  If the pattern is followed by a /,
      only directories and subdirectories match.
```

So, to move the directory `run` to the top level directory `x`, and then delete the rest, you can do:

```
shopt -s globstar; mv x/**/run/ x/  && find x/ -type d -empty -delete
```

The `shopt` command enables the `globstar` option. The `mv x/**/run/ x/` will move any subdirectories named `run` (note that this only works if there is only one `run` directory) to `x` and the `find` will delete any empty directories.

You could do the whole thing in the shell with extended globbing, if you like, but I prefer the safety net of `find -empty` to be sure no non-empty directories are deleted. If you don't care about that, you can use:

```
shopt -s globstar; shopt -s extglob; mv x/**/run/ x/ && rm -rf x/!(run)
```

Answer (score 6):

Definitely more verbose, but doing the job in one step:

#### Assuming you have python installed

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import shutil
import os
import sys

dr = sys.argv[1]

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dr):
    # find your folder "run"
    for pth in [d for d in dirs if d == sys.argv[2]]:
        # move the folder to the root directory
        shutil.move(os.path.join(root, pth), os.path.join(dr, pth))
        # remove the folder (top of the tree) from the directory
        shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(dr, root.replace(dr, "").split("/")[1]))
```

#### How to use

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `get_folder.py`
2. Run it with the root directory (containg your unzipped stuff) and the name of the folder to "lift" as arguments:

   ```
   python3 /full/path/to/get_folder.py /full/path/to/folder_containing_unzipped_dir run
   ```

And it is done:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a very interesting solution but I prefer not to use any python script for various reasons. Thanks tho!

Comment: No problem. Maybe it is of use to anyone else. Curious to why though? I am pretty sure many applications already use python.

Comment: Mainly since placing the .py file anywhere will be problematic as I have to assume it is in the same place for every linux machine that will be running my script (and my script is run across many platforms).

Comment: @Idos just curious, which platforms ? Python is quite widespread. I don't think it is installed on Mac OS X by default, but most Linux distributions do have it

Answer (score 4):

#### Perl solution

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use File::Copy::Recursive qw(dirmove);

my @wanted;
find(sub{ -d $_ && $_ eq "run" && push @wanted,$File::Find::name}, $ARGV[0]);
dirmove("$wanted[0]","./run");
```

The way this works is simple: `find()` subroutine will traverse given directory tree recursively, find the directory whose name is `run` and push it into array of wanted filenames. In this case, we assume there should be only one file in the list, thus once command completes, we use `dirmove()` from `File::Copy::Recursive` module, and move it to current working directory from which script was called. Thus in your case you would call it from parent directory to `x`.

Original directory tree:

```
$ tree                                                                                                                   
.
└── levelone
    └── leveltwo
        └── levelthree
            └── run
                ├── file1
                ├── file2
                └── file3
```

Result:

```
$ ~/find_dir.pl .  
$ tree 
.
├── levelone
│   └── leveltwo
│       └── levelthree
└── run
    ├── file1
    ├── file2
    └── file3
```