# Command that deletes all old files, folders and sub-folders

Tags: linux, files, find, rm

I need a command that deletes all files, folders and sub-folders that were not updated longer than 31 days.
I tried this one

`find . -mindepth 1 -mtime +31 -exec rm -rf "{}" \;`

But if I have hierarchy like this

```
.
├── old_sub_folder1
└── old_sub_folder2
    ├── old_file
    └── old_sub_folder3
        └── new_file
```

where `old_*` are old folders\files and `new_file` is a new file.

This command will delete all contents. Because `old_sub_folder2` date was not updated after `new_file` was created.

I need a command that would not delete old_sub_folder2/old_sub_folder3/new_file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you added the `-r` option to your `rm` command. This will delete the folders even if they are not empty.

You need to do this in two steps:

1. Delete only the **old files**:

   `find . -type f -mtime +31 -delete`
2. To delete any old folders, if they are empty, we can take a peek [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8430/how-to-remove-all-empty-directories-in-a-subtree), and tweak it a bit:

   `find . -type d -empty -mtime +31 -delete`

Comment: Sounds great. But I should not delete new empty folders.

Comment: Then just do step 1. This will leave any folders intact, deleting only the files.

Comment: remember that removing a file will change mtime of directory.

Comment: And that empty directories could exist and be new. The OP want to delete old stuff, not empty stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
find  . -type d ! -name . -mtime +31 -exec sh -c '
   case $(find "$1" ! -mtime +31 -exec echo x \; -prune) in
      "" ) rm -rf "$1" || echo "Error could not delete folder \"$1\"" ;;
   esac
' {} {} \;
```

From the current directory we launch `find` and look at only `directories` that have not been updated since the last 31 days. And in each of these directories we in turn dive in and look for anything that is not older than 31 days, and upon finding it we echo a dummy character and also prune any forward search (ideally we should just terminate our search here by means of `-quit` but that's not `POSIX` hence we settle for `-prune`).

Then we look for the result of this `find` operation and should it turn out to be empty we know that not even one element (file/dir/link/etc.) was new and hence this dir. is safe for deletion.