# How to delete all "stuff" (dir and files) older than x days?

Tags: find, delete

I am aware of `find -mtime +x -delete`, but how do I use it - or use it in a script - in order to delete all the "old stuff" (including hidden files) ?
Eg, if I have a dir `target_dir`:

- delete all folders and subfolders of `target_dir` whose content in any deep level has not changed by X days (i.e. delete old directory tree branches)
- delete all the files in `target_dir` that didn't change by X days

**Edit**: related to [this topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/358113/command-that-deletes-all-old-files-folders-and-sub-folders) but the accepted answer there doesn't really work, because by first removing files we "update" the modification date of the old directories so that they are not removed in the second step... also not sure about possible hidden files/directories..

Comment: Does Stéphane's answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/689901/21334) help?

Comment: @doneal24: thank you.. I think I have found a simpler alternative...

Answer (score 0):

After several tests, the simplest approach that I did find was to use simply:

`find /path/to/dir -mtime +30 -delete`

These delete everything excepts the branches that have newer stuff.

Note however that at the same time: (a) this would not work: `find /path/to/dir/* -mtime +30 -delete`; and (b) if `/path/to/dir` contains only old stuff and it has not been updated itself it will be deleted itself.

So my approach, as I wanted to keep the directory, is to run the first `find` command and then to check if the directory still exist, and if not, I recreate it.

Comment: If you have `/path/to/dir/foo/`, `/path/to/dir/foo/bar/`, and `/path/to/dir/foo/bar/tmp`, all with only old file, the last path will be deleted, the middle path's mtime updated, and the first path unchanged. You then have a branch that contained only old files that still exist after your commands are run.

Comment: Hmm... I'll double check and report... it worked with a very complex old directory, but I'll double check, thanks...

Comment: @doneal24 This is not my experience.. with `find` v4.8.0 (Ubuntu 22.04) `path/to/dir` is removed if it contains only old stuff, even if it has 3 or 4 directory levels...