# Sync two directories: same filename, different fileending, different filecontent

Tags: shell-script, rsync, synchronization, machine-learning

I have 2 folders with subdirectories. One with training images and one with training labels.

- One image belongs to exactly one label
- The image and the label have different content
- The image and the label can be found in similar paths. 
  e.g.:

  - **images**/18/1334/image1.**webp**
  - **labels**/18/1334/image1.**png**
- The filename (not the extension) is the same
- There can be multiple files in one subdirectory

How can I remove every label which has no corresponding image (and the other way round)?
For example:

images:

```
.
|---18
     |---a1
     |    |---a1.webp
     |    |---a11.webp
     |---a2
     |    |---a2.webp
     |---a3
```

labels

```
.
|---18
     |---a1
     |    |---a1.png
     |    |---a11.png
     |---a2
     |    |---a2.png
     |---a3
          |---a3.png
```

---

Okayish solution (remove files if there are no corresponding labels or images):

```
.
|---18
     |---a1
     |    |---a1.*
     |    |---a11.*
     |---a2
     |    |---a2.*
     |---a3
```

Best solution (remove the folders which are empty now, too):

```
.
|---18
     |---a1
     |    |---a1.*
     |    |---a11.*
     |---a2
          |---a2.*
```

The asterisk* stands for webp or png.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `find` and `bash`:

`cd` to the parent directory of `images` and `labels` and run:

```
find . \( -name "*.webp" -o -name "*.png" \) -type f -exec bash -c '
if [ "${1##*.}" = "webp" ]; then
  file=${1/\/images\//\/labels\/} 
  file=${file%webp}png
else
  file=${1/\/labels\//\/images\/}
  file=${file%png}webp
fi
[ ! -f "$file" ] && echo rm "{}"
' bash {} \;
```

You need to remove the `echo` to really delete the files.

To delete your empty directories, see [How to remove all empty directories in a subtree?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8430/how-to-remove-all-empty-directories-in-a-subtree).

Comment: No need to remove the echo; just pipe it into a shell:  `./my-script | sh`  Most all scripts should be written this way, if you want to **look** at what is going to happen before you actually commit to doing it.

Comment: Awesome answer! Thank you very much. I still need a bit of experience to build something like that!. There is only an easy to fix error: At the moment we delete the file which does not exist. We want to delete the file which exists but has no corresponding file.