# Find empty directoris OR directories with no files in them recursively

Tags: linux, find, directory

There's the `find . -type d -empty` command, but that only finds literally empty directories.

What I want to achieve is something a little bit more complex: I want to find empty directories or directories that ONLY have other directories or empty directories, and this rule should be passed on recursively.

So for example, in this directory structure:
`~1/11/111/`
It would find `1/`, `1/11/` and `1/11/111/`
But if at any point in the tree there's a file, for example in this case if there's a file in `1/11/111/file1` then none of them before the file should be returned. So if there's an empty directory `1/11/111/1111/` next to `1/11/111/file1`, 1111 should be returned.

The reason I want this is because I want to delete my empty folders.

Now I could probably do that by running `find . -type d -empty -delete` over and over again, but I want a way to kind of visualize it before I remove them.

Is this possible?

Comment: If, eventually, you're going to remove all the empty directories, then you can just iterate the tree depth-first, and remove them as you see them. With the subdirectories removed, the parent directories would then be empty, too. I think there are questions about that here on the site

Comment: just `find . -depth -type d -empty -delete` might even do

Comment: @ilkkachu The `-depth` is implicit with `-delete`.

Comment: questions as this, [How to remove all empty directories in a subtree?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8430/170373), but then I just realized you wanted to print them _before_ deleting, and I suppose that's slightly harder

Comment: I'd do this by piping `find` through `sort` into an awk-script to filter out directories having content (take a half hour or so, which is longer than I'd spend for this category).

Answer (score 5):

To see the directories deleted, just insert `-print`:

```
find . -type d -empty -print -delete
```

This would delete any sub-hierarchy beneath the current directory that is empty, while displaying the pathnames of the directories that are deleted.

The `-delete` action implies `-depth`, i.e. the traversal will start at the bottom of the directory structure and work its way up (a depth-first-traversal).  This means that any directory that may be considered for deletion will already have its sub-directories processed (and these wil have been deleted if they were empty).

Example:

```
$ mkdir -p 1/2/3/4/5/6
```

```
$ tree
.
`-- 1
    `-- 2
        `-- 3
            `-- 4
                `-- 5
                    `-- 6

6 directories, 0 file
```

```
$ find . -type d -empty -print -delete
./1/2/3/4/5/6
./1/2/3/4/5
./1/2/3/4
./1/2/3
./1/2
./1
```

```
$ tree
.

0 directory, 0 file
```

If one directory has a file:

```
$ mkdir -p 1/2/3/4/5/6
```

```
$ touch 1/2/3/file
```

```
$ tree
.
`-- 1
    `-- 2
        `-- 3
            |-- 4
            |   `-- 5
            |       `-- 6
            `-- file

6 directories, 1 file
```

```
$ find . -type d -empty -print -delete
./1/2/3/4/5/6
./1/2/3/4/5
./1/2/3/4
```

```
$ tree
.
`-- 1
    `-- 2
        `-- 3
            `-- file

3 directories, 1 file
```

To list the directories that only contain subdirectories, but without deleting them (using `bash`):

```bash
shopt -s globstar
for dir in ./**/; do
    if [ -z "$(find "$dir" ! -type d -exec echo x \;)" ]; then
        printf '%s\n' "$dir"
    fi
done
```

This would loop over all the subdirectories in the current directory (reclusively, using the `**` shell glob), and then try to find something that is not a directory in any of them.  If something is found, then that directory is not empty, otherwise the pathname of the empty directory is outputted.

With GNU `find`, you could add `-quit` to the very end of the above `find` command (after `\;`) to speed things up a bit.

Comment: Thanks! That's more or less what I'm looking for. Just one more question: since -delete is recursive, is -exec also recursive? Also, since the `-print` option only seems to work with the `-delete` option, is there any way to list them all the way I wanted without deleting them? EDIT: Nevermind I can make it do that with the -depth argument.

Comment: @user361323 `find` is recursive over the search paths that you give it. The `-delete` or `-exec` will just act on the current pathname being investigated at the moment.  To list the empty directories without deleting them, just remove the `-delete` action (this will list the directories that are empty, but not the ones that contain only directories).

Comment: @user361323 See added bit at the end.

Answer (score 2):

To print the empty directories without deleting any, we'll have to do more than just remove the empty ones from the leaves up.

Something like this may work:

```
find dir/ -type d ! -exec sh -c \
  'find "$1" ! -type d -print -quit | grep -q . >/dev/null' sh {} \; -print
```

The outer `find` finds each directory, and runs *another* `find` on each of them. The inner `find` looks to see if that directory (recursively) contains any non-directories, and returns a true value if so. The outer `find` then prints each directory that returned false (i.e. didn't contain any non-directories).

That's rather slow, though, with the recursive `find`s. A better solution might involve caching directories where files were found, or an approach that would start from empty directories and work up until a branch that contains file(s).