# Print only files, directories containing files and empty directories

Tags: find, ls, directory-structure, tree, indexing

I am trying to index some LTO tapes (and some hard disks as well) and would like a simple output, stored in a text file. Something like the example below:

```
...
/home/norg/Desktop/empty\ dir/
/home/norg/Documents/file.txt
...
```

The "empty dir" folder is, of course, an empty folder. Notice how folders like "Desktop" and "Documents" are only printed because they have contents inside them. In other words, `/home/norg/Desktop/` would never be printed, unless it were empty.

I've tried things like `ls -RFad /home/norg/` and some `find` syntaxes to varying success. The trickiest part is having the empty directories printed, but not the full ones. I hope this makes sense. Thanks.

Another thing to mention, I would really prefer this to work in one go, as I will be using this with tape and want to have as little reads as necessary to reduce wear.

Comment: In the example, does \ belong to the actual filename? or is it there just to escape the space? If the latter, is escaping a must? What other characters should be escaped? Will you accept directories without trailing slashes? [Directory is also a file](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690), so "print only files and empty directories" is equivalent to "print files". Do you mean "regular files"? or "non-directories"? (these terms are not equivalent). Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: question is not clear enough

Comment: Read `man find`, an empty. directory is `\( -type d -links 2 \)`

Comment: @waltinator your claim only applies to some filesystem types,do it is not helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find empty directoris OR directories with no files in them recursively](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/531618/find-empty-directoris-or-directories-with-no-files-in-them-recursively)

Comment: @schily: Which filesystem types in use on Unix & Linux don't have `.` and `..`?

Comment: @waltinator ZFS and WOFS don't have them, but this is not the point. The dirty hack from UNIX from the 1970s to hardlink `.` and `..` is definitely not granted by POSIX.

Comment: @waltinator I know your method doesn't work in Btrfs.

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
find /home/norg \( -type d -empty \) -o -type f
```

This will list empty directories and regular files which are below `/home/norg`.

Although the question title mentions "directories containing files", those are not printed as an item, per the ¡question text.

Also note that it only prints *regular files*. If you have e.g. fifos or devices, those would not appear (and if you had a folder only containing a device, it would not be printed, either). In case you wanted to also include them, you may use

```bsh
find  \( -type d -empty \) -o -not -type d
```